# Can we compare class probabilities between different methods in caret?

Tags: r, probability, classification, caret

I am using the caret package in R for binary classification and I want to compare different methods (e.g., random forest, SVM, ANN, PLS-DA...). I consider the class probabilities as a "certainty score" for classification (e.g., one observation with class probability of 0.9 is classified with more certainty than one observation with class probability of 0.60). My question is: can we compare class probabilities between different methods? For example, I realized that PLS-DA gave probabilities centered around 0.50 (probabilities were rarely above 0.70), while SVM gave probabilities that would be considered as more certain (much more probabilities abode 0.70), even though the AUC were similar for both methods. Does that mean that SVM is better than PLS-DA?

Comment: To clarify, I think this post has two questions: 1) is it right to treat class probability as the model's certainty to predict it? 2) all things the same, is model with high class probability is better compared to models with about 0.5 class probability?